# DirectShow RGB-YUV filter

Tags: directshow, rgb, yuv, vp8

I would like to encode video in my app with VP8. I use RGB24 format in my app but VP8 DirectShow filter accepts only YUV format (http://www.webmproject.org/tools/#directshow_filters).

I've googled the "RGB to YUV directshow filter" but no success. I don't want to write this filter myself from scratch, so I would appreciate if you help me with the information on where to find such filter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [Geraint Davies' YUV transform filter](http://www.gdcl.co.uk/downloads.htm) to see if it supports the conversion.

Comment: Thanks, at least this one works! But can I use it in my commercial app? I see the GDCL license the first time..

Comment: "Unless otherwise stated, all the materials available from this website remain copyright GDCL, and are available on the following terms: to use, modify and redistribute the software in source or binary form, provided that you retain a notice in the source code of the form “Portions copyright GDCL”." Sounds to me like it's fine, but I'm no expert. To be sure, you could email Geraint?

Comment: Sound to me fine also. Thank you, I will investigate further.

Comment: Geraint said: "If you're just redistributing a binary from the website, you don't need to do anything. This only applies if you are redistributing source"

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Vista you can use Color [Converter DSP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd443213%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), does this help?

If you know how to implement a transform filter, I have a fast YUV to RGB algorithm somewhere. I used DirectShow a looong time ago, so I can't be of anymore help than this :P

Comment: I need to support Windows XP also : (