# Open Source YUV420 to RGB source code or directshow

Tags: c++, video, directshow

I need a directshow filter that converts a decoder input that is yuv420 into rgb. Any source code or directshow filter available???

Answer (score 3):

- [Color Converter DSP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819079) - API easily convertible to DirectShow filter
- [libswscale](https://www.ffmpeg.org/libswscale.html) - source code
- [YUV Transform](http://www.gdcl.co.uk/downloads.htm) - filter
- Intel Media SDK
- See also:

  - [DirectShow RGB-YUV filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673609/directshow-rgb-yuv-filter)
  - [YUV to RGB conversion. RGB file structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13753846/yuv-to-rgb-conversion-rgb-file-structure?rq=1)
  - [avcodec YUV to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24970182/avcodec-yuv-to-rgb?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

We released an open-source one in the [video processing project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/videoprocessing/) that handles MEDIASUBTYPE_I420 (planar YUV420).